# Как игнорировать изменения в гугл таблицах

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Для таблицы создан триггер на редактирование.

```
function onEdit(e) {
 var CurDate = new Date();
 var CurNumDay = new Number(CurDate.getDay());
 var DateFrom = new Date();
 DateFrom.setDate(DateFrom.getDate() + (4-CurNumDay));
 DateFrom.setHours(0,0,0,0);
 var DateTo = new Date();
 DateTo.setDate(DateTo.getDate() + (6-CurNumDay));
 DateTo.setHours(20,0,0,0);
 if (e.user=="<тут мой адрес почты гугл>") {
   Logger.log("доверенный пользователь, на время проверять не надо");} 
 else {
   Logger.log("Анонимный пользователь, требуется проверка на время");
   if ((CurDate>=DateFrom) && (CurDate<=DateTo)) {
     Logger.log("Анонимный пользователь, разрешенное время, изменения разрешены");}
   else {
      Logger.log("Анонимный пользователь, запрещенное время, изменения запрещены");
     Logger.log("Новое значение:  "+e.value);
     Logger.log("Старое значение: "+e.oldValue);
     Logger.log("Новому значению присвоим старое значение");
     e.value=e.oldValue;
     Logger.log("Новое значение:  "+e.value);
     Logger.log("Старое значение: "+e.oldValue);
   }}
}
```

Сейчас выполняю его от анонимного пользователя. в лог получаю 2 сообщения:

```
Анонимный пользователь, требуется проверка на время 
Анонимный пользователь, запрещенное время, изменения запрещены
```

Это очень хорошо. То что мне нужно. Правила написаны правильно.

Теперь вопрос - Как можно игнорировать изменения или новому значению присвоить значение до изменения.

Делаю так: e.value=e.oldValue

В логе видно что новое=старое, но в таблице сохраняется новое значение

Как можно перехватить сохранение нового значения и не вносить изменения?

Comment: В общем решение найдено.

В блоке, где есть строка "Logger.log("Анонимный пользователь, запрещенное время, изменения запрещены");", следующей строкой надо написать следующую команду


 if(!e.oldValue){e.range.setValue(" ")} else {e.range.setValue(e.oldValue)};


и тогда если пользователь Анонимный и время не допустимое его введенное значение, через секунду, заменяется на предыдущее значение.


Правда осталась одна проблема. В таблице только 12 столбцов. По непонятной причине скрипт срабатывает только в первых 5 столбцах.

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Попробуйте разобраться с типами триггеров, т.к. в вашем коде намешано лишнего. Вы не можете запретить вносить изменения, если их приняла система. Единственным выходом в этой ситуации может быть "перезапись" на старое значение, которое передается в параметр триггера события Edit или в простой триггер onEdit.

```
function onEdit(e){
  e.oldValue
  ...
```

Но там не все медом намазано. В некоторых случаях при работе с датами значение может оставаться пустым.